# How to add text on top of two side by side images

Tags: html, css, image, text

I'm trying to put text on top of two images that are side by side and together fill out the entire site. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="main">
        <img src="city.jpg" class="city" alt="city">
        <img src="couple.jpg" class="couple" alt="couple">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    display: flex;    
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 152.5vh;
  }
  
  .city {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .couple {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
  }
```

Both of the images are side by side without any space in between. I want to add text to the middle of the side so sort of on top of both images. What could I try to do?

I have looked online to find a solution but nothing worked or was simply too hard to understand and to implement. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

personally I wouldn't do that with flex but with grid

Simple grid 2rows, 2 cols.

text div take 2 cells of first row, and image on second row, each in 1 cell

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 152.5vh;
}

.text {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  color: #222222;
}

.city {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.couple {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.city img,
.couple img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="text">
    1 title for 2 image
  </div>
  <div class="city">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/800/600" alt="city">
  </div>
  <div class="couple">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/85/800/600" alt="couple">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. My problem was maybe formulated a bit misleading. I want the text to be sort of on the two images. Like have it not over them but maybe in the center of both. How would I do that?

Comment: to be clear let say if we say "on top" that would mean images would be under text (under = y axis), over would mean z axis like a layer. So you would like to have text over the 2 images in center?

Comment: thats right. over the two images on the center

Answer (score 0):

so to answer your latest comment "thats right. over the two images on the center"

we still can use grid for images, in add here I put the grid in position relative, and the text in absolute. You can play with top value.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 152.5vh;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #222222;
}

.city {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.couple {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.city img,
.couple img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="text">
    1 title for 2 image
  </div>
  <div class="city">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/800/600" alt="city">
  </div>
  <div class="couple">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/85/800/600" alt="couple">
  </div>
</div>
```